# Http Posting in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin.forms, http-post, xamarin.forms.entry

Am facing a problem in Posting data from my Entires via a parametrized url , i don't know why it's happening, the URL returns a certain message after posting  , below is my URL :

http://bbs.eamobiledirectory.com/Mobile/MobileApi.aspx?Action=NewSalesReport&username=USERNAME&assID=ASSIGNID&repdetails=details&appoi_date=date.

and this is how am posting my data :

```
    void OnSubmitReport(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            PostData();
        }


        public async void PostData()
        {


            string details = report_details_entry.Text;
            string date = nextappointment_entry.Text;


            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                        {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("unm", USERNAME),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string >("assinID", ""+ASSIGNID),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("details", details),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("appoi_date", date)

   });

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://bbs.eamobiledirectory.com/Mobile/MobileApi.aspx?Action=NewSalesReport",formContent);


        }
```

what i want is to submit the data in the Entries after wards i return a message in a DisplayAlert Message.

Comment: your example shows a GET, not a POST.  Are you sure you need to use POST?  The parameter names in your code also do not match the ones shown in your example url.

Comment: yes i wanted to post @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you figure out why the FormUrlEncodedContent not working(i would really like to know why its not working)

you can solve your problem by posting this way:

```
var url = string.Format("http://bbs.eamobiledirectory.com/Mobile/MobileApi.aspx?Action=NewSalesReport&unm={0}&assignID={1}&report_details={2}&appoi_date={3}",
                USERNAME,
                ASSIGNID,
                details,
                date);

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, null);

var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```